# Cluster Apache Mysql (MariaDB)

Tags: linux, apache, debian

Estoy configurándome un servidor local en 4 máquinas en cluster de Linux Raspbian Stretch.
Ahora mismo tengo apache configurado con balancer-manager para distribuir el tráfico a ordenador correspondiente según la web que se pida.

Las webs están alojadas en cada servidor en clúster por separado, <strike>y lo que quiero es que todo el alojamiento vaya a un único disco duro alojado en otro servidor que lo tenga montado.</strike>

¿Es posible esto?

---

## EDIT

---

Esquema que tengo actualmente:

- Cluster Master

  - Apache2 (Proxy Balancer-Manager) -> Redirige el tráfico a los slaves
- Cluster Slave 1

  - Apache2, PHP7, MariaDB, PhpMyAdmin, Hosting
  - VirtualHosts
- Cluster Slave 2 y 3

  - Copia de Slave 1 (cambiando IP's evidentemente)

---

Ahora mismo lo que necesito es poder configurar:

- Acceder al FTP desde fuera de mi casa y que acceda a cluster slave según necesidad.
- Acceder a cada PhpMyAdmin de cada VirtualHost.

Como decía arriba, la primera idea, que ya me han descartado en una respuesta por tráfico excesivo, era alojarlo todo en un disco duro a parte.

Ahora me lo replanteo y me gustaría consejos sobre cómo montarlo para que funcione un clúster casero en condiciones.

Actualmente ya tengo home server (sin cluster) montado y funcionando perfectamente. Al hecho de tener un mini-custer en casa para desarrollo y muestras, no es porque tenga mucho tráfico, pero empieza a no procesar algunas peticiones.

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta, espero te sirva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si te he entendido bien (edita la pregunta si no es así para que se entienda mejor) pero quieres que los ficheros esten "compartidos" por todos los servidores y que solo los tenga uno de ellos.

En este caso lo que tiene que montar es un [`NFS`](https://enavas.blogspot.com.es/2008/12/compartir-archivos-entre-mquinas-linux.html). Puedes hacerlo también con carpetas compartidas [`samba`](http://www.linuxforthefuture.com/compartir-carpetas-con-samba/) o con [`SSHFS`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)

Si va a ser entre sistemas ´Linux´ te recomiendo `NFS` o `SSHFS`, si tambien quieres que pueda acceder un sistema `Windows`, tiene que ser `samba`.

El problema de esto es la latencia del propio sistema, ya te tanto el acceso como la escritura de los archivos se hace por red, mucho más lento que si tuviera acceso local.

Por lo que veo que tienes montado, lo que quieres es redundancia por si alguno cae, y seguramente caiga por consumo de recursos o por peticiones/carga. Tener esos ficheros compartidos por red hace que las peticiones sean más lentas ya que el acceso a esos recursos también lo es.

Una solución es usar [`Gluster`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluster_File_System) que en teoría (y por las pruebas que he podido hacer funciona) no tiene esa limitación, pero también requiere de más `hardware`.

**Edito:**

Lo que comentas es lo siguiente, te respondo por cada parte:

> Acceder al FTP desde fuera de mi casa y que acceda a cluster slave
>   según necesidad.

Puedes hacer un [`NAT`](https://www.xatakamovil.com/conectividad/nat-network-address-translation-que-es-y-como-funciona) de puertos entre esos servidores y tu IP publica de manera que puedas acceder al `FTP` de cada una de las maquinas desde los puertos que tú mismo configures, te recomiendo dos cosas:

- Comenzar a partir del puerto 62162
- Usar `SFTP` que es básicamente `SSH` a través de `FTP` con el puerto `22` o el que tengas configurado en el `SSH`
- Nunca exponer directamente el puerto `SSH` expón en su defecto alguna maquina de salto, desde la cual pueas saltar a las demas, no todas a la vez. Así tienes un unico punto de entrada y si pasa algo lo puedes cortar.

> Acceder a cada PhpMyAdmin de cada VirtualHost.

No te lo recomiendo es un fallo de seguridad muy gordo usar `PhpMyAdmin`, cualquiera te lo puede pillar y atacarlo hasta que se aburra. Te recomiendo usar `MysqlYog` o `MySQLWorkbench` a través de un túnel `SSH`, es mucho más seguro y ademas puedes limitar el acceso por IP para que no puedan atacar tu `MySQL`, en `MySQL` puedes limitar las conexiones a `localhost` y así nadie más puede acceder. Luego con el túnel tú te conectas vía `SSH` y luego a `MySQL` como `localhost`.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta para clarificar :) Gracias por la respuesta @Sakrow

Comment: Editada, @Sakrow :)

Comment: Gracias Sakrow, la marco como correcta. Lo probaré!